# Does disavowing a subdomain work? Will disavowing a domain include all the subdomains?

Tags: subdomain, disavow-links

I currently disavow the domain `example.com` using [Google's disavow links tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main).

What can I do if I want do disavow a subdomain? i.e. `spam.site.com`. I'm also assuming that if I were to disavow the domain it would include all subdomains?

Comment: Please review my [updated answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/57878/12183) which has been confirmed correct by Google now as well.

Answer (score 11):

After receiving [clarification on this from John Mueller at Google](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111386732836817610825/posts/eTzXKKetx5G), disavowing a root domain will also disavow all other sub domains under it.

For example, disavowing:-

```
domain:example.com
```

Will also disavow:-

```
sub23.example.com
sub4646.example.com
www.example.com
```

You can of course, disavow individual sub domains like `domain:sub23.example.com` though which will only affect that individual sub domain.

[Here is a link to the old answer from the revision history](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/revisions/57878/2)

Comment: any proof? From what I see on webmaster forums (including google product forums!) disavowing a domain disavows all subdomains.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not, no proof. I'm sure this was how it was originally provided in terms of handling sub domains but with so many others (as you point out) stating that disavowing a root domain will also disavow all sub domains, I've [raised a discussion point](https://plus.google.com/111386732836817610825/posts/eTzXKKetx5G) in the Technical SEO community on Google+ and called in John Mueller to see if he can confirm for us.

Comment: @jitbit - you were right, I've updated my answer and cited source.

Comment: Good work tracking down John Mueller.

Comment: Good work, thanks @zigojacko . I could see this question on many forums and communities and it is asked many times from 2014 or so.. wondering why Google is not updating in their webmaster's guidelines?

Comment: @BhargavJoshi Hmm, yeah they could explicitly clarify about sub-domains in disavow files [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487) which would be useful. But if anyone searches about it, I'm sure they'll come across this page now.

Comment: True. Nowadays, spammers are using subdomains of a popular domain for toxic backlinks.So need to be extremely cautious while disavowing these subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Geoff's answer:

When you talk about disavow, are you talking about Google's Webmaster Tools disavow links tool? If so, then this isn't the correct way to go about it; I will explain at the end.

Firstly all domains, for example: `example.com`, is a website with the Top-Level Domain being `.com`.

So in a simple way `example.com` is a subdomain of `.com`, obviously entering `.com` doesn't bring anything up, however the subdomain `example.com` will bring up the website as it is a separate entity.

Now expanding this, `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` these are both to completely separate websites. `www` and `non-www` websites both redirect (normally if set up correctly) to the same server and resolve as the DNS setting normally has 2 `A` records pointing to the domain name - one for `non-www` traffic and one for `www` traffic.

Now thinking about this I'm sure you can now understand that `subdomain.example.com` acts in the same way that `www` does as this is also a subdomain of `example.com`.

Now with regards to disavowing links, if you mean Google Webmaster Tools disavow links, this option should only be used after all necessary manual removal of the links has been made as this will show Google that you have taken the time and effort to amend whatever it is that you are doing (this is more in the case where you have been penalized by Google for unnatural links, etc...).

So in summary:

- `.com` is a top-level domain (TDL).
- `example.com` is (basically) a subdomain of `.com`, however this is
  your domain name.
- `www.example.com` is a subdomain of `example.com`, but is often
  redirected back to the same place as `example.com`. This can
  be used for anything you want, but remember it is completely
  different.
- Disavow each sub-domain individually, as diavowing `example.com` will not disavow `a.example.com`

Comment: Any prooflink? Seems like you're wrong, disavowing a domain DOES include all subdomains: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ru/2012/10/a-new-tool-to-disavow-links.html (and even disavowing a subdomain will sometimes disavow the ENTIRE root domain)

Comment: "Disavow each sub-domain individually, as diavowing example.com will not disavow a.example.com" appears to be incorrect based on clarification from John Mueller in Zigojacko's answer.