# How do I disavow all links from a domain that has duplicate content on many subdomains?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have several links from a website that hosts duplicate content from various subdomains, all link to my page and according to LinkDetox these links all have a medium reputation.

Since I know that this is all duplicate content, does it make sense to disavow all duplicate links or would you disavow the whole domain?  I think that would should also disavow all subdomains, does it?!

Comment: I would like to warn you about disavowing links and sites like LinkDetox. These are valuable services and options, but please be aware that these sites trade on your fear and disavowing links is something to be generally avoided. Even low quality links add up and just because a junk site links to you does not mean it is harming your ranking. Google knows who the junk sites are and knows that not all links should count against the target site. Normal junk links are somewhat forgiven. You want to disavow obvious negative SEO. The rest you want to really think about very carefully.

Comment: I suggest reading the whole FAQ portion of this post: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2012/10/a-new-tool-to-disavow-links.html

Comment: Also, you might like this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71644/should-i-disavow-blogs/71676#71676

Comment: Indeed, I did not ask HOW to disavow all links from those pages. I was wondering if the same links from duplicate content can harm your site. In this example, there are 30 subdomains just copies of the original and the link itself is not great but ok in my point of view.

Comment: From Google: Q: I didn’t create many of the links I’m seeing. Do I still have to do the work to clean up these links?
A: Typically not. Google normally gives links appropriate weight, and under normal circumstances you don't need to give Google any additional information about your links. A typical use case for this tool is if you've done link building that violates our quality guidelines, Google has sent you a warning about unnatural links, and despite your best efforts there are some links that you still can't get taken down. ***Supports our point of view.***

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that yes, if you disavow the whole domain, all subdomains might as well be disavowed as well. If you want to make sure that you keep some links from some of the subdomains, you should probably go through the effort and disavow only the ones with duplicate content. If I got you correctly, they got duplicate content because they copy content from their own subdomains, right?
By the way, have you set the anchor texts when using link detox, so their evaluation is more accurate?

Comment: That is my understanding as well, but this would be a much better answer if you found a reference for how it works.

Comment: You're correct, sorry. Does this help? (It's from 2012, though, the FAQ section on http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2012/10/a-new-tool-to-disavow-links.html) Look for >> "If a freehost is very new or rare, we may interpret this as a request to disavow all links from the entire domain."

Comment: This seems to having been asked on Stackexchange before (hence could count as another reference): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57870/does-disavowing-a-subdomain-work-will-disavowing-a-domain-include-all-the-subdo

Comment: exactly, they copied their content and made it available through 30+ sites, so i got 30+ links with the same anchor text, rather of low quality even though they might not be harmful. I guess I should keep 1-2 links of these and disawovong the others?!

Comment: That would be my suggestion, yes.